# How can I send an sms from an iphone webapp using a link?

Tags: iphone, web-applications, sms

I saw a tutorial on the web which said I could do this:

http://geekswithblogs.net/MobileLOB/archive/2009/03/13/sending-sms-in-iphone-web-app.aspx

```
<A HREF=”SMS:2323232232”/>TXT ME</A>
```

: but when I click this link on my iphone the sms app is opened but the body of the message is empty

Answer (score 2):

With `sms:` URL scheme you can only specify the destination number. Starting with iOS 4 it's possible to [send an SMS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SystemMessaging_TopicsForIOS/Articles/SendinganSMSMessage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010416-SW1) from a **native** app using MessageComposer.

Read again your linked tutorial. It said that adding `body=...` doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I meant does using MessageComposer actually fill in the body of the message on iphone4

Comment: Yes, it does. If you follow the linked documentation you'll see MFMessageComposeViewController has a 'body' property described as'The initial content of the message'.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is because you've copied the quotes from somewhere, which converted it into text-quotes.

```
<A HREF=”SMS:2323232232”/>TXT ME</A>
```

should be

```
<A HREF="SMS:2323232232"/>TXT ME</A>
```